# Naming a newly-created instance based on user input

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a class (let's call it `foo.m`) and my main `barAppdelegate.m`. In my delegate, I want to create an instance of `foo.m` dynamically based on the user input (i.e., the name of this instance should be what the user enters) and I need to keep track of lots of these.

Comment: first of all y do you want the instance name to be dynamic and second of all i dont think it is possible in any programming language. (as far as i can think of).

Comment: When you count php as programming language ... - but the name doesn't matter at all.

Comment: and name of the instance is for the programmers and it has nothing to do with users taste.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to create an `NSMutableDictionary` in which to store the instances of `foo` that you create (these are the objects) and set the name to be the key as an `NSString`.

Answer (score 2):

There's absolutely no reason in Objective-C to specify the *name of a variable* at runtime. Variables are for you, the programmer (and the compiler). You need to slightly rethink your program.

You need every instance of your `Foo` class to be associated with a user-entered string. You should therefore give the class an instance variable to hold that string. When you create the objects, put them into a collection -- either, as PengOne suggests, a dictionary where you can again access them by the provided string, or simply an array.

If you really think that you will need to retrieve the instances primarily *by that string*, then a dictionary is a good choice. If you will only occasionally need to get at the instances that way, use an array and have a look at [`indexOfObjectPassingTest:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-SW21)

```
NSUInteger idx = [myArray indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if( [[obj name] isEqualToString:stringToTest] ){
        *stop = YES;
        return YES;
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ClassName myClass = NSClassFromString (@"classname");

ClassName *object = [[myClass alloc] init];
```